# what is the purpose of Context in JMS?

Tags: java, jms

I would like to know what is the purpose of Context at JMS and why I need (or should) initialise it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's used to find your JMS provider and the various factories, topics, queues and other resources.  Typically this is done via JNDI and so you need an initial context to start searching from.